# Create Table On Radio Button Click

Tags: php, html

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I've put together the code below which creates a list of dates and associated radio buttons pertinent to the user which is logged on.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password")or
die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database");


$result = mysql_query("SELECT userdetails.userid, finds.dateoftrip, detectinglocations.locationname, finds.userid, finds.locationid, detectinglocations.locationid,   finds.findname, finds.finddescription FROM userdetails, finds, detectinglocations WHERE finds.userid=userdetails.userid AND finds.locationid=detectinglocations.locationid AND finds.userid = 1 GROUP By dateoftrip ORDER BY dateoftrip DESC");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) 
// table is empty 
  echo 'There are currently no finds recorded for this location.'; 
  else
 { 
  echo"<table>\n";
  while (list($userid, $dateoftrip, $findname) =
    mysql_fetch_row($result))
  {

    echo"<tr>\n"
    .
     "<td><input type='radio' name='show' dateoftrip value='{$dateoftrip}' /></td>\n"
    ."<td><small>{$dateoftrip}</small><td>\n"
    ."</tr>\n";
  }
  echo'</table>';
}

?>
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="style10"> 

<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if (isset($_POST['show']))
      $dateoftrip = intval($_POST['show']);

  echo"<table>\n";
  while (list($dateoftrip, $findname) =
    mysql_fetch_row($result))
  {

    echo"<tr>\n"

    ."<td><small>{$findname}</small><td>\n"
    ."</tr>\n";
  }
  echo'</table>';
}

      ?>
<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" />
</form>
```

What I'd like to be able to do, which I'm having difficulty with, is upon the radio button being selected I would like another table to render on screen with the list of 'findnames' applicable to the date selected.

I've managed to get the first part working, but upon the radio button being selected, nothing happens.

I've spent quite a bit of time on this but I just can't seem to find the answer.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps have a look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks

**Amended Code**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "passowrd")or
die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database");


$result = mysql_query("SELECT userdetails.userid, finds.dateoftrip, detectinglocations.locationname, finds.userid, finds.locationid, detectinglocations.locationid,   finds.findname, finds.finddescription FROM userdetails, finds, detectinglocations WHERE finds.userid=userdetails.userid AND finds.locationid=detectinglocations.locationid AND finds.userid = 1 GROUP By dateoftrip ORDER BY dateoftrip DESC");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) 
// table is empty 
  echo 'There are currently no finds recorded for this location.'; 
  else
 { 
  echo"<table>\n";
  while (list($userid, $dateoftrip, $findname) =
    mysql_fetch_row($result))
  {

    echo"<tr>\n"
    .
     "<td><input type='radio' name='show' onclick dateoftrip value='{$dateoftrip}' /></td>\n"
    ."<td><small>{$dateoftrip}</small><td>\n"
    ."</tr>\n";
  }
  echo'</table>';
}
?>

<table width="300" border="1">
<tr id="findname"><th>Findname</th></tr>

</table>
<script type="text/javascript">    
function displayRow(){        
var row = document.getElementById("findname");  
if (row.style.display == '')  
row.style.display = 'none'; else row.style.display = '';    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need JQuery or javascript. [.load() is the easiest to do](http://api.jquery.com/load/) it will load a page or a div from a page into a div thats already present on the page. you can do this [.Click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) or [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this. I have to admit to not being particularly experienced in Javascript, but, I've had a go at put together what I think you were suggesting. The only thing i'm not sure about is how to tie up the correct findname or names, if there is more than one. I've amended my original post to reflect the change in code. Could you possibly have a look at this and provide some guidance on how I can link the button and the correct details. Many thanks